# Refining LayeredGraphPlot by selecting downward links only

Tags: graphs-and-networks

This codes:

```
 ClearAll[wam, vLabels, sa, wag];
 wam = {
 {0, 0.03, 0, 0.03, 0.02, 0.04},
 {0.05, 0, 0.07, 0, 0, 0.03},
 {0.06, 0, 0, 0.07, 0, 0},
 {0.05, 0, 0.03, 0, 0.04, 0},
 {0.06, 0, 0, 0, 0.05, 0.04},
 {0.01, 0.02, 0.07, 0.01, 0, 0.05}};
 vLabels = {1 -> AGF, 2 -> CO12, 3 -> MA1, 4 -> MA2, 5 -> EGW, 6 -> CST};
 sa = SparseArray[wam];
 wag = Graph[sa["NonzeroPositions"], EdgeWeight -> sa["NonzeroValues"],
 DirectedEdges -> True, EdgeLabels -> "EdgeWeight"];

 LayeredGraphPlot[wag, PlotTheme -> "Minimal", VertexLabels -> vLabels]
```

produces:

[image]

How can I create a graph with downward links only? Or upward links only? In two separate plots, I like to see down- and up-direction graphs.

**EDIT**

In my actual code, `wag` in the question above is `wag3` constructed as follows:

```
wagNew = WeightedAdjacencyGraph[vnames, wam/.{0.->Infinity}]
wamNew= WeightedAdjacencyMatrix[wagNew];
sa=SparseArray[wamNew]
wag3 = Graph[sa["NonzeroPositions"], 
EdgeWeight -> sa["NonzeroValues"], DirectedEdges -> True, 
EdgeLabels -> "EdgeWeight", VertexLabels -> vLabels, 
PlotTheme -> "Minimal", ImagePadding -> 10, 
GraphLayout -> "LayeredDigraphEmbedding"];
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
EL[dir_ : Up] := g |-> 
  EdgeList[g, 
   _?((dir /. {Up -> Less, Down -> Greater}) @@ 
       PropertyValue[{g, VertexList[{#}]},  VertexCoordinates][[All, 2]] &)];
```

***Examples:***

```
wag2 = Graph[sa["NonzeroPositions"], 
   EdgeWeight -> sa["NonzeroValues"], DirectedEdges -> True, 
   EdgeLabels -> "EdgeWeight", VertexLabels -> vLabels, 
   PlotTheme -> "Minimal", ImagePadding -> 10, 
   GraphLayout -> "LayeredDigraphEmbedding"];

EL[Up] @ wag2
```

> ```
> {1 -> 2, 1 -> 6, 4 -> 1,  4 -> 3, 4 -> 6, 5 -> 1, 5 -> 6}
> ```

```
HighlightGraph[wag2, Graph @ EL[Up] @ wag2, 
 GraphHighlightStyle -> "DehighlightHide"]
```

[image]

```
HighlightGraph[wag2, EL[Up]@wag2, GraphHighlightStyle -> "Thick"]
```

[image]

```
EL[Down] @ wag2
```

> ```
> {1 -> 4, 1 -> 5, 1 -> 7, 2 -> 1, 2 -> 3, 2 -> 7, 3 -> 1, 3 -> 4,   
>  4 -> 5, 5 -> 7, 6 -> 1, 6 -> 2, 6 -> 3, 6 -> 4, 6 -> 5, 6 -> 7}
> ```

```
HighlightGraph[wag2, Graph@EL[Down]@wag2, 
 GraphHighlightStyle -> "DehighlightHide"]
```

[image]

```
HighlightGraph[wag2, EL[Down]@wag2, GraphHighlightStyle -> "Thick"]
```

[image]

Comment: Change `EL[dir_ : "None"] := g |-> EdgeList[g, _?((dir /. {"None" -> Equal, "Up" -> Less, "Down" -> Greater}) @@ PropertyValue[{g, VertexList[{#}]}, VertexCoordinates][[All, 2]] &)];` then `Manipulate[HighlightGraph[wag2, EL[dir]@wag2, GraphHighlightStyle -> "Thick"], {{dir, "None", "highlight"}, {"None", "Up", "Down"}, ControlType -> RadioButtonBar}]`

Comment: @kglr: Thanks for the code. Very nice! (Thanks also go to @Bob for Manipulate). I tried the code with other layered graphs. It gives an error `EdgeList: A graph object is expected at position 1 in EdgeList...`, although I give a layered graph `g` as input for `EL[Down]@g` function. What might be troubling here?

Comment: @TugrulTemel, `LayeredGraphPlot` produces a `Graphics` object (not a `Graph` object); so we need to use `Graph` with the option `GraphLayout -> "LayeredDigraphEmbedding"` to generate the input graph for `EL` to work.

Comment: @kglr: I understand it. Originally, my new directed graph is `wUpstream`, which is of the form `WeightedAdjacencyGraph[.]`. I convert it to `SparseArray` by `sa=WeightedAdjacencyMatrix[wUpstream]` and then use your code for `wag2`. it still does not work. May be the way I create `sa` is not correct?

Comment: can you post the example that gives error?

Comment: @kglr: I will do so now.

Comment: @kglr: In the EDIT code, I simply used `wam` in the question to show the steps I followed to create a `Graph[]` like you did.

Comment: @kglr: I also edited `wam` matrix in the question because it was not a square matrix (my mistake). Therefore, I was a bit surprised that your code worked even with a non-square matrix.

Comment: @kglr: I solved the problem by `wag2 = Graph[EdgeList[wUpstream], 
  EdgeWeight -> PropertyValue[wUpstream, EdgeWeight], 
  VertexLabels -> "Name", GraphLayout -> "LayeredDigraphEmbedding"];
HighlightGraph[wag2, Graph@EL[Up]@wag2, 
 GraphHighlightStyle -> "DehighlightHide"]`. It works and no error. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Re _"surprised that your code worked even with a non-square matrix"_, when the first argument of `Graph` is a list of integer pairs (like `sa["NonzeroPositions"]`)  `Graph` takes the vertex list as `Range[1, Max@sa["NonzeroPositions"]]`.

Comment: @kglr: Thank you for the clarification. I have no further question.